# Azure VM - strange fail

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I was using my Azure VM and when installing SQL Express the RDP session stopped.
Cant reconnect RDP, but asks for password and if wrong denies access.
Alsso tried to reboot and shutdown from Azure Web Panel and Azure PowerShell with no success. What can I do more?

Thanks,

Paulo

Comment: This is more of a ServerFault question. You might have better luck there.

Comment: If you have an interrupted VM connection from RDP, I've seen this same problem, in which you cannot reconnect to the VM.  The way I've gotten around it is by first, try to remove and add the RDP Endpoint.  Second, if this does not work, try to stop and then start the Cloud Service the VM is running on.

Comment: Thanks for lhe tips, but didnt work...

Comment: Well, good job MS! Once more the solution is delete a machine a recreate it... well this is a non relliable platform...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change password for your RDP in order to reconnect, try this maybe it will work.

***Reset by using the Azure portal***

First, sign in to the Azure portal and then select Virtual machines on the left menu.
Reset the local administrator account password

1.Select your Windows VM and then select Reset password under Help. The Reset password window is displayed.

2.Select Reset password, enter a username and a password, and then select Update.

3.Try connecting to your VM again.

Reset the Remote Desktop Services configuration

This process will enable Remote Desktop service in the VM, and create a firewall rule for the default RDP port 3389.

1.Select your Windows VM and then select Reset password under Help. The Reset password window is displayed.

2.Select Reset configuration only and then select Update.

3.Try connecting to your VM again.